# Java Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been working on implementing a doubly linked list from scratch in Java, and if anyone has time, could you critique it?

```
class Node {
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    int data;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        prev = null;
        next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    Node head;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
    }

    public void insert(int d) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(d);
            return;
        }

        if (head.data > d) {
            Node holder = head;
            Node newNode = new Node(d);
            head = newNode;
            head.next = holder;
            holder.prev = newNode;
            return;
        }

        Node tmpNode = head;

        while (tmpNode.next != null && tmpNode.next.data < d) {
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }

        Node prevTmp = tmpNode;         
        Node insertedNode = new Node(d);

        if (tmpNode.next != null) {
            Node nextTmp = tmpNode.next;
            insertedNode.next = nextTmp;
            nextTmp.prev = insertedNode;
        } 
        prevTmp.next = insertedNode;
        insertedNode.prev = prevTmp;    
    }

    public void delete(int d) {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
            return;
        }

        if (head.data == d) {
            head = head.next;
            if (head != null) {
                head.prev = null;
            }
            return;
        }

        Node tmpNode = head;

        while (tmpNode != null && tmpNode.data != d) {
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }

        if (tmpNode == null) {
            System.out.println("That node does not exist in the list");
            return;
        }

        if (tmpNode.data == d) {
            tmpNode.prev.next = tmpNode.next;
            if (tmpNode.next != null) {
                tmpNode.next.prev = tmpNode.prev;
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        Node tmpNode = head;

        while (tmpNode != null) {
            System.out.print(tmpNode.data + " -> ");
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }

        System.out.print("null");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Can use Generics for Node to provide something for more then just ints.

```
class Node<T> {
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    T data;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        prev = null;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

then same for your linked list implementation.

```
class LinkedList<T> {
    Node<T> head;

    ...

    public void insert(T d) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node<T>(d);
            return;
        }

    ...
```

Can make T extends Comparable and use comparable interface to compare if they are less/greater than

Answer (score 2):

1. Your are creating something similar to `java.util.LinkedList`, thus it is best practice to use same or similar method names.
2. Your list is sorted. Whenever you search for an element, change this loop:

   ```
   while (tmpNode != null && tmpNode.data != d) {
       tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
   }

   if (tmpNode == null) {
       System.out.println("That node does not exist in the list");
       return;
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   while (tmpNode != null && tmpNode.data < d) {
       tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
   }

   if (tmpNode == null|| tmpNode.data != d) {
       System.out.println("That node does not exist in the list");
       return;
   }
   ```

   It stops whenever the element can't be found.
3. Instead of `System.out.println`, use a `boolean` return value to indicate success.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be simplified since this is a basic example and it should be clear and simple. 
You have two variables that aren't actually needed:

- `newNode`: when inserting smaller than the first.
- `prevTmp`: when inserting after while.  It can be `tmpNode`.

Just remove them and not bother newcomers with looking why you used those.

Comment: I think you should elaborate more on your answer, there isn't much here